# how do I change rownames in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried searching high and low and cannot find an answer to my question.

I am creating an R shiny app for the first time. As part of the app I read in a tab delimited file with column names. Later I then create a matrix and I want to assign the row names to be the column names of the tab delimited file I originally read in and I have no idea how to do this. The server part (I have left out the rest of the code that isn't relevant to this question) looks like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

imported_data_reactive <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$data_import
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  read.table(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
})

stats <- reactive({
  matrix(NA, ncol({imported_data_reactive()}),5)
})
```

how do I then assign the rownames? I tried:

```
reactive({
  rownames({stats()}) <- colnames({imported_data_reactive()})
})
```

but this does not work. I'm sure there is a very simple answer, but it is not obvious to me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that with reactive values. Code like `row.names(df) <- colnames(df)` works fine, so if it acceptable to manage reactions in

> observeEvent()

you can do read data in dataframe and change row names or other thing that you can't do with reactive values.

Comment: thanks for the response! If I use observeEvent() to assign the row names, I am getting the warning "Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment". Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No, better to show your code, i don't know about this error

Comment: I changed my df to a reactiveValue and that has fixed the problem